# Admin account constantly locked

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have tried multiple solutions from stack and other sites and the outcome is the same. My admin account is constantly locked. I don't really know what more I can do. Here are some screenshots:
[image]

Both my admin accounts aren't stated as locked. While trying to login as ADMIN I get 'locked account' alert and with TWEANT account I get 'wrong passwor'.

I have tried with 'wwv_flow_fnd_user_api.UNLOCK_ACCOUNT(‘ADMIN’);' and running 'apxchpwd.sql' script. Nothin helped and I am out of ideas. Maybe there is something wrong with my installation but while running

```
[oracle@OracleDatabase oracle-rest]$ java -jar ords.war install simple

Verify ORDS schema in Database Configuration apex with connection host: localhost port: 1521 service name: pdbwindow

Jul 24, 2017 11:59:42 AM oracle.dbtools.rt.config.setup.SchemaSetup install
INFO: Oracle REST Data Services schema version 3.0.11.180.12.34 is installed.
2017-07-24 11:59:42.947:INFO::main: Logging initialized @11856ms
Jul 24, 2017 11:59:44 AM
INFO: The document root is serving static resources located in: /home/oracle/oracle-rest/conf/ords/standalone/doc_root
2017-07-24 11:59:48.514:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
2017-07-24 11:59:49.354:INFO:/ords:main: INFO: Using configuration folder: /home/oracle/oracle-rest/conf/ords
2017-07-24 11:59:49.363:INFO:/ords:main: FINEST: |ApplicationContext [configurationFolder=/home/oracle/oracle-rest/conf/ords, services=Application Scope]|
Jul 24, 2017 11:59:49 AM
INFO: Validating pool: |apex||
Jul 24, 2017 11:59:49 AM
INFO: Pool: |apex|| is correctly configured
Jul 24, 2017 11:59:49 AM
INFO: Validating pool: |apex|al|
Jul 24, 2017 11:59:49 AM
INFO: Pool: |apex|al| is correctly configured
Jul 24, 2017 11:59:49 AM
INFO: Validating pool: |apex|pu|
Jul 24, 2017 11:59:50 AM
INFO: Pool: |apex|pu| is correctly configured
Jul 24, 2017 11:59:50 AM
INFO: Validating pool: |apex|rt|
Jul 24, 2017 11:59:50 AM
INFO: Pool: |apex|rt| is correctly configured
config.dir
2017-07-24 11:59:51.322:INFO:/ords:main: INFO: Oracle REST Data Services initialized|Oracle REST Data Services version : 3.0.11.180.12.34|Oracle REST Data Services server info: jetty/9.2.z-SNAPSHOT|
2017-07-24 11:59:51.338:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@86ab0b2{/ords,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-07-24 11:59:51.339:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler@14767a6f{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-07-24 11:59:51.340:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler@6e6017e7{/i,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-07-24 11:59:51.388:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@5714f585{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2017-07-24 11:59:51.394:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @20302ms
Jul 24, 2017 12:00:04 PM
INFO: Configuration properties for: |apex||
cache.caching=false
cache.directory=/tmp/apex/cache
cache.duration=days
cache.expiration=7
cache.maxEntries=500
cache.monitorInterval=60
cache.procedureNameList=
cache.type=lru
db.hostname=localhost
db.port=1521
db.servicename=pdbwindow
debug.debugger=false
debug.printDebugToScreen=false
error.keepErrorMessages=true
error.maxEntries=50
jdbc.DriverType=thin
jdbc.InactivityTimeout=1800
jdbc.InitialLimit=3
jdbc.MaxConnectionReuseCount=1000
jdbc.MaxLimit=10
jdbc.MaxStatementsLimit=10
jdbc.MinLimit=1
jdbc.statementTimeout=900
log.logging=false
log.maxEntries=50
misc.compress=
misc.defaultPage=apex
security.crypto.enc.password=******
security.crypto.mac.password=******
security.disableDefaultExclusionList=false
security.maxEntries=2000
security.requestValidationFunction=wwv_flow_epg_include_modules.authorize
security.validationFunctionType=plsql
db.password=******
db.username=APEX_PUBLIC_USER

Jul 24, 2017 12:00:04 PM
WARNING: *** jdbc.MaxLimit in configuration |apex|| is using a value of 10, this setting may not be sized adequately for a production environment ***
Jul 24, 2017 12:00:04 PM
WARNING: *** jdbc.InitialLimit in configuration |apex|| is using a value of 3, this setting may not be sized adequately for a production environment ***
Jul 24, 2017 12:00:04 PM oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolBase initInactiveConnectionTimeoutTimer
INFO: inactive connection timeout timer scheduled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has happened to me and I found out the solution was to confirm and re-confirm  you're using the right apxchpwd.sql because if you run the 5.1 on 5.0, no errors but the exact issue you're described.

Heck, copy the file from another installation and give it a try..

Comment: I tried using file from unzipped apex folder and it didn't produce errors. Whereas using file from oracle server directory resulted in errors.

Comment: This is partially true answers as I was executing this file onto my CDB$ROOT but APEX was installed on PDB1. It may have been the cause. Not sure thought, as I had to reinstall it because of other errors.